Using lmer() function
I have troubles using the lmer() function. It looks like it has something to do with the versions of the packages "lme4" and "Matrix".
This happens when I try to load the lme4 function from library:
> library(lme4)
Loading required package: Matrix
Warning messages:
1: package ‘lme4’ was built under R version 4.3.3 
2: In check_dep_version() : ABI version mismatch: 
lme4 was built with Matrix ABI version 1
Current Matrix ABI version is 0
Please re-install lme4 from source or restore original ‘Matrix’ package

Example when I try the lmer() function:
fit.lmer <- lmer(rt ~ 1 + fnoise*fangle + (1|id) + (1|id:fnoise) + (1|id:fangle),
+                  data = Data)
Error in initializePtr() : 
  function 'cholmod_factor_ldetA' not provided by package 'Matrix'

I expected that the lmer() would work.
I tried:
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("lme4")

I have the most recent version of Rstudio btw.

Please add the R tag and mark the inline code
